# How can I modify the apalike bibliography style to remove square bracketed citation in my reference list?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

Currently using BibDesk with TeXShop (for mac). The `apalike` bibliography style is pretty much perfect for how I like (and more importantly my advisor likes) to do my references.

The only problem is that the citation that comes up in the text [Author, Year] is repeated before each entry in my reference list at the end of the document. Is there a way to remove this so I may just have the Author, Year, Title etc. as normal just without this extra square bracketed part at the beginning?

Here's what it looks like:

[image: What the citation looks like in the text]
[image: The text citation is repeated before the reference]

Many thanks for any contribution you may be able to give in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried loading the [natbib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) package with the options `square` and `authoryear`? (For parenthetic-style citation call-outs, be sure to use `\citep` instead of `\cite`.)

Comment: AMAZING thank you so much! Had tried natbib already but didn't make the connection that I needed to use \citep instead of \cite. Brilliant, you are an angel

Comment: I'm blushing...

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions, while using the `apalike` bibliography style, for suppressing the material that's otherwise printed in square brackets at the start of each bibliographic entry:

- Load the [natbib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) citation and bibliography management package. To create parenthesis-style citation call-outs, use `\citep` instead of `\cite`. Provide the option `square` if you want square brackets used in the citation call-outs, and provide the option `round` if you want round parentheses used in the citation call-outs.
- Load the [apalike](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.sty) citation management package. This package supports just `\cite` instructions, and it will create parenthesis-style citation call-outs, using round parentheses. It's possible to provide more than one argument in a `\cite` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%% bibtex entry information obtained from http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103502969629
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Barbara2002161,
author  = "John M. Barbara and Larry W. Esposito",
title   = "Moonlet Collisions and the Effects of Tidally Modified Accretion in {Saturn's} {F}~Ring",
journal = "Icarus",
volume  = "160",
number  = "1",
pages   = "161-171",
year    = "2002",
issn    = "0019-1035",
doi     = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/icar.2002.6962",
url     = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103502969629",
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[square]{natbib} % <- new
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here I cite the paper \citep{Barbara2002161}.

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```